# Use LINQ to XOR Bytes Together

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use LINQ to to `XOR` bytes together in an array? I'm taking the output of an MD5 hash and would like to `XOR` every four bytes together so that I can get a 32 bit `int` out of it. I could easily do this with a loop, but I thought it was an interesting problem for LINQ.

```
public static byte[] CompressBytes(byte[] data, int length)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (i * length + j >= data.Length)
                break;
            buffer[j] ^= data[i * length + j];
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

---

Slightly off topic, but is this even a good idea? If I need a `int`, would I be better off with a different hash function, or should I just take the first 4 bytes of the MD5 because `XOR`ing them all wouldn't help any? Comments are welcome.

Comment: Post your loop solution.

Comment: sorry if I'm misreading this, but did you mean 'every four bytes' instead of 'every four bits'?  Given the loop and target being 32-bits, I wanted to check.

Comment: You are correct; typo on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IEnumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) function (not actually LINQ, but most people refer to the LINQ-related extension methods as LINQ) to perform a custom aggregate. For example, you could compute the total XOR of a list of `byte`s like this:

```
var xor = list.Aggregate((acc, val) => (byte)(acc ^ val));
```

You can create a virtually unreadable chain of extension method calls to do what you're after:

```
int integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(Enumerable.Range(0, 3).
              Select(i => data.Skip(i * 4).Take(4).
                  Aggregate((acc, val) => (byte)(acc ^ val))).ToArray(), 0)
```

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the questioner's constraints. He wants to XOR groups of 4 bits together in the byte array.

Comment: Sorry - my question wasn't as clear as I thought. I posted my loop solution. (Actually a nested loop solution.)

Comment: @codekaizen, @Daniel: Yeah, I read the question too hastily. This edit should address the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

To address the "off topic" part, I'd suggest just lopping off the first 32 bits of the MD5 hash. Or consider a simpler non-crypto hash such as [CRC32](http://nitokitchensink.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54131#1012328).

Like other cryptographic hashes, MD5 is supposed to appear as random as possible, so XOR'ing other bytes won't really make a difference, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need xor of 2 byte arrays: byteArray1.Select((x, i) => (byte)(x ^ byteArray2[i])).ToArray();